# Change UrlManager for just one controller

Tags: php, url, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing

My Yii 1.x application has UrlManager configured to generate / use URLs like `content/show.html`:

```
'urlManager'=>array
(
    'class'=>'UrlManager',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
    'rules'=>array
    (
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
    )
),
```

I have also overridden `CUrlManager` -> `UrlManager` to implement [Qiang's solution](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/404/hyphenation-of-routes-in-url-management/), that allows me to use hyphenation of routes, that is `an-action-name` that points to standard `anActionName`.

I'd like to keep it that way, but I'd like to extend it, so for one controller (used for AJAX calls) it does not uses `urlSuffix` and generates / uses URLs in this format: `ajax/get-published-files`.

Since I'm a complete newbie (nearly ignorant) in regular expressions, I haven't conducted much of my own researches, before asking, because I don't even know, where to and what for actually search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make your suffix part of your pattern instead of your global configuration

for example :

```
    'ajax/<action:\w+>'=>'ajax/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>.html'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>.html'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>.html'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>.html'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

and ofc drop the suffix part of your urlManager config

Comment: I was trying to find the plugin that allowed you to use multiple suffixes, but rules become an array in an array based on their suffix/prefix, but for just 1 controller it seemed a bit overkill